# Layout code for Facebook feed content

Tags: android-layout, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to display the Graph API output for the Facebook Feed using the Facebook style, as it appears on the web and mobile app. Is there available reference code/layouts for this? Thanks!

Comment: You mean try to implement like Android Facebook Hackbook ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to implement the Feed in Android code like the SDK examples. The SDK examples such as Hackbook don't have a Feed example.

Comment: If You mean to about Layout Design then you have to custom implement it as you want.

Comment: I thought so. I'm looking for an example, because the home feed `/me/home` is complicated. If there is really none, then could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. If your requirement is about the Layout and Desing that looks in Facebook sdk/ app then you must have to made such type of design for yours.

There is nothing like to develope such type of layout. Yes there are some Demo example that can be useful to develop such type of UI integration.

So hope you got the point.

For any query comment here.

Enjoy Coding. :)

Comment: can you give some idea how Facebook dynamically generate such kind of layout (news feed layout)?